# PopOver issue in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ipad, uipopovercontroller

On my landing view's navigation bar I have button which when clicked displays a `UIPopoverController` and I init the contentViewController with a class named `A`. I use the following code to display my `UIPopoverController`:

```
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect
                                    inView:self
                  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                  animated:YES];
```

This works fine and a tableView is displayed inside the `UIPopoverController`, now the thing is I have to display another `UIPopoverController` when user selects any one row of the displayed `UITableView`. The thing is when I try to add the new `UIPopoverController` it isn't getting displayed. After trying a lot of things, I have noticed the `inVIew : self` might be at fault. At the time of displaying the first `UIPopoverController` when I do `po self` the name of the view which is displayed is printed. But for the second `UIPopoverController` which is supposed to be displayed after selecting a row, the `po self` prints the name of the class which I want to display in the second `UIPopoverController`. Which I think maybe the reason why the `UIPopoverController` in not getting added to the view and hence not being displayed. Please let me know how should I solve this. Thanks.

Comment: try with tablename instead of self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are asking to display a popover when a popover is already showing. That's impossible. You cannot display two popovers simultaneously. You should rethink your interface.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir !